# Cannot use shared back-end access database: "file already in use"

Tags: ms-access-2003

I have a small database that I want to use with my colleagues. We all need to read and write data in the tables, so I split the database in two files (back-end and front-end): database_BE.mdb and database_FE.mdb

As we are a small team and the database in not sensitive, I did not bother create access rights, passwords etc. I just put database_BE in our shared drive and a copy of database_FE in everyone's directory on the network.
Everything worked fine, but now I get the "file database_BE.mdb is already in use" (error 3045) when both of us open our database_FE at the same time.

I tried solving the problem by ckecking the permissions in the folder where the database_BE.mdb is, but all users have full read/write rights.

Within Access, I set the following properties:

[image: pic0]

I also looked in the group and users permissions, and set the following properties:

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

But I keep having the same error.

I thus have one question:

- How can I set my database so that all users can use it at the same
  time?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT : This morning, everything worked fine again. I suspect that my boss has slightly different privileges on the network because the problem appeared when he connected to the database... I will investigate on that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen to me recently.
Make sure all the users have READ/WRITE permission for the shared folder where the backend is hosted.

Hope you get it sorted out.